# NotNull Annottation in Java

Tags: java, android

Looking through old questions and can't figure out when to use and why use `@NonNull` annotation in Java (Android). And why I can annotate as method as variable then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using it on a variable, IntelliJ IDEA uses it to indicate that the specified element cannot be `null`. If you are using it on a method, it says that the method should not return `null`.

Comment: And if in code it appears to be null then nothing happen? It is just for developing purpose?

Comment: @KirillZotov It's just so a smart IDE/tool can provide useful semantic warnings when a possible (or guaranteed) NPE can be detected based on static analysis of null/not-null (aided by such annotations). Has absolutely no bearing/effect in the run-time.